# multiprocessing python : how to split jobs

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I tried to write a python for multiprocessing. I have been reading online, but I still don't understand how to write it.

My script :

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import ctypes

def func(M, j, :
    coor_i = np.zeros(1000)
    coor_j = np.ones(1000) # In reality it is loaded from a txt
    A = np.square(coor_i - coor_j)
    a = A.sum
    M[j] = a

 for i in range(1,100) :
     M = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, np.ones(i))
     p = mp.Process(target = func, args = (coor_i, j)) for j in range(1,i)

     p.start()
     p.join()

     print(M)
```

I look online and I have seen - 'mp.Pool', 'processes', 'mp.Queue'

Thank you very much.

Comment: First - what's the actual problem you're running into here?  Second - this code isn't syntactically valid as the indentation's broken.

Comment: You need to fix the indentation first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your first mistake is to not return anything from your `func()` function. In python all values are references to objects in memory, and when you do an assignment, you're replacing the referenced value with a new object. So doing `M = -M` is not mutating `M`'s object, but creating a new one, and changing the reference `M` within the scope of the function.

What it means is that your function will *always* return `None`:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Pool
>>> def func(M): # if you call with M=1
...    # M==1 here
...    M = -M
...    # M==-1 here
...
>>> M = 1
>>> M = func(M)
>>> print(M)
None
```

To fix this you need to make it *return* the value:

```
>>> def func(M):
...     return -M
...
>>> print(func(1))
-1
```

Then, the best way to parallelize the work would be to use a pool of processes so that you can control how many instances run in parallel, adapting straight [from the documentation examples](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
>>> def func(M):
>>>     return -M
... 
>>> pool = Pool(processes=4)                # start 4 worker processes
>>> results = []
>>> for i in range(1,100):
...     results.append(pool.apply_async(func, [i]))    # evaluate "func(i)" asynchronously
...
>>> print [result.get() for result in results]
[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15, -16, -17, -18, -19, -20, -21, -22, -23, -24, -25, -26, -27, -28, -29, -30, -31, -32, -33, -34, -35, -36, -37, -38, -39, -40, -41, -42, -43, -44, -45, -46, -47, -48, -49, -50, -51, -52, -53, -54, -55, -56, -57, -58, -59, -60, -61, -62, -63, -64, -65, -66, -67, -68, -69, -70, -71, -72, -73, -74, -75, -76, -77, -78, -79, -80, -81, -82, -83, -84, -85, -86, -87, -88, -89, -90, -91, -92, -93, -94, -95, -96, -97, -98, -99]
```

Another way to do the same thing would be to use:

```
>>> print(pool.map(func, range(1,100)))
[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15, -16, -17, -18, -19, -20, -21, -22, -23, -24, -25, -26, -27, -28, -29, -30, -31, -32, -33, -34, -35, -36, -37, -38, -39, -40, -41, -42, -43, -44, -45, -46, -47, -48, -49, -50, -51, -52, -53, -54, -55, -56, -57, -58, -59, -60, -61, -62, -63, -64, -65, -66, -67, -68, -69, -70, -71, -72, -73, -74, -75, -76, -77, -78, -79, -80, -81, -82, -83, -84, -85, -86, -87, -88, -89, -90, -91, -92, -93, -94, -95, -96, -97, -98, -99]
```

That being said, if all you're doing is indeed negating the value (or something that simple) — which I guess you aren't — then it is better to *NOT* use parallelizing, as python and your microprocessor will vectorise the work and have it run faster:

```
>>> print([-M for M in range(1,100)])
[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15, -16, -17, -18, -19, -20, -21, -22, -23, -24, -25, -26, -27, -28, -29, -30, -31, -32, -33, -34, -35, -36, -37, -38, -39, -40, -41, -42, -43, -44, -45, -46, -47, -48, -49, -50, -51, -52, -53, -54, -55, -56, -57, -58, -59, -60, -61, -62, -63, -64, -65, -66, -67, -68, -69, -70, -71, -72, -73, -74, -75, -76, -77, -78, -79, -80, -81, -82, -83, -84, -85, -86, -87, -88, -89, -90, -91, -92, -93, -94, -95, -96, -97, -98, -99]
```

here's a metric, as ran on my machine with python2:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("[-M for M in range(1,100)]", number=100000)
0.6327948570251465
>>> def test():
...     pool.map(func, range(1,100))
...
>>> timeit(test, number=100000)
31.26303195953369
```

---

edit:

the issue with your question is that it is quite unclear what you're trying to achieve, and what you're trying to do. Usually the first path to parallelization is to do a version non-parallelized, and try to parallelize the things that will work better and have no mutual exclusion.

But one thing that strikes me in your code is that for each iteration of your `range(1,100)` loop you're actually waiting for a process to finish before launching a new one:

```
 for i in range(1,100) :
     M = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, np.ones(i))
     # Create process
     p = mp.Process(target = func, args = (coor_i, j)) for j in range(1,i)

     # Start a process
     p.start()
     # wait for the process p to finish before going on
     p.join()
     # will continue when p has finished
```

If you want to address this you can either use the `Pool` as shown in my example or:

```
 for i in range(1,100) :
     M = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, np.ones(i))
     # Create process
     p = mp.Process(target = func, args = (coor_i, j)) for j in range(1,i)

     # Start a process
     p.start()
     # wait for the process p to finish before going on
     p.join()
     # will continue when p has finished
```

So a quick improvement would be:

```
 processes = [] # keep a list of all the processes
 for i in range(1,100) :
     M = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, np.ones(i))
     # Create process
     for j in range(1,i):
         p = mp.Process(target = func, args = (coor_i, j))
         # Append to processes list
         processes.append(p)
         # Start a process
         p.start()

# wait for all processes to have finished before quitting (or going on)
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

so I just updated the code: there you start all processes in one loop, and in the other loop you're blocking until they finish. The [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) is making current process blocking until the other process finishes, so the second loop makes sure that every process has finished before finishing your snippet, or going on with further code.

---

So for the "generator" issue, I did not notice you were doing a `for j in range(1, i)` on your `mp.Process` line, and thus not appending a process to the process list, but a list generator.

What happens is that actually your conde *CANNOT* work, and should fail upon compilation because:

```
p = Process(target = func, args = (coor_i, j)) for j in range(1 ,i)
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

if you correct this the following way:

```
>>> (p = Process(target = func, args = (coor_i, j)) for j in range(1 ,i))
```

then your original code *CANNOT* work, because `p` is not a process, it is a list generator and `p.start()` cannot exist:

```
>>> p.next()
<Process(Process-5, initial)>
>>> p.next()
<Process(Process-6, initial)>
>>> p.next()
<Process(Process-7, initial)>
>>> p.next()
<Process(Process-8, initial)>
>>> p.next()
<Process(Process-9, initial)>
```

So instead of using the for one liner in this case is a bad idea, which is corrected using the traditional for.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more precise about my code. I have edited it so it is more similar to my real code.

What I am trying is to parallelize the for loop, instead of the function itself.

Comment: Somehow, there is an error message regarding  - processes[-1].start() - 
'generator' object has no attribute 'start'

Also would you mind explaining why the "for p" loop should be placed outside of the "for i" loop? And why -1 is needed for "processes[-1]"?

Comment: I did not try the code, and actually I see what's wrong… but I have to go, I'll get back to fix it later

Comment: It is a good news. Thanks you. I should have made it clearer. I know how to do mp.Array, but somehow it is just not in parallel.